# How do I clean streaks on this external sliding door?

Tags: doors, windows, cleaning

[image: Window streaks]

[image: Window streaks]

I have an external sliding door where one section (the sliding part) has a number of large top-to-bottom streaks on both the frame and glass. They appear to start at the top where the opening was rendered.

I have no idea what they are but they started a little while after the rendering was done (but after it had set). I am guessing it's lime or a similar additive that's leached for some reason (although this hasn't happened on any other door or window).

Any idea on what it might be or how I can clean it? I have tried pressure washing, limescale remover, bathroom cleaner, glass cleaner and Big Wipes spray but nothing has worked. I also tried polishing the glass with a drill-mounted pad but it only made a small difference.

Comment: Have you tried scraping with a razor blade? Are you sure they're actually streaks of something _on_ the glass and not a chemical or mechanical etching _into_ the glass?

Comment: Are you sure the glass isn't coated? The photos look like they were taken by a camera with a UV filter on the lens… or it's on the glass. If you're not sure, take a photo with the door half open so the camera captures half through the glass & half straight out to the background. A UV filter will make a big difference as to how distinct the clouds look. A plastic film coating on the glass would of course be far more susceptible to [permanent] damage.

Comment: vinegar will remove lime, as will lime-away, CLR, etc. Any acid works, try spit or coke to see if an acidic cleaner will be effective.

Comment: @dandavis - OP already said they tried descaler. idk what CLR is.

Comment: @Tetsujin [CLR](https://clrbrands.com/) is a pretty common brand here in the States. I'm sure you have an equivalent that goes by a totally different name there.

Comment: @FreeMan - Might have an equivalent, but without knowing vaguely what it is, that might be tough to find ;)) See https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/CLR

Comment: Sorry... CLR - Calcium, Lime, Rust. It's a cleaning product.

Comment: @Tetsujin CLR is a lactic acid solution in water, pH about 2, plus lauramine oxide surfactant.

Comment: Vinegar or similar?

Comment: I found a Zep calcium, lime and rust cleaner available in the UK so I'll try that and see how/if it works, thanks everyone!